# Is there any uncertainty of the magnetic moment of muons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

Charged elementary particles with non zero spins like electrons and muons are observed to carry magnetic moment. This can be modeled using a charged rotating disk. If the distributions of mass and charges are the same, the gyromagnetic ratio is always q/2m. In quantum mechanics, the gyromagnetic ratio of elementary particles is multiplied by 2 (aka g-factor), while quantum electrodynamics adds a small correction to the g-factor due to interactions with virtual particles, and we have measured the magnetic momentum of electrons at an extremely high precision.

However, the magnetic moment of muons is a bit ambiguous. According to the uncertainty principle, there is an uncertainty of the mass/energy of unstable particles. Because both the elementary charge and angular momentum are absolutely precise, either the magnetic moment or the g factor should possess some degree of uncertainty. Has experimental measurements on the magnetic moment of muons observed such uncertainty?

Comment: Uncertainty of energy implied by muon's lifetime seems too low for the experiments measuring its mass to detect it in distribution of measured values.

Comment: I'm not sure whether such measurements even consider the possibility that muon masses are not all the same, usually everybody assumes it is a sharp parameter.

Comment: See muon g-2 experiments https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon_g-2 . also search in Physics here

Comment: Why do you assume that uncertainty in energy via the HUP will cause uncertainty in the g-factor?

Comment: If there is no uncertainty in the muon’s magnetic moment, it means g-factor is no longer precise.